# Using PHP to supply an in memory pdf from a Java generator

Tags: java, php, pdf

I am creating a web front end for clients to download their reports.  The program that the company uses is written in Java and consists of 31 mysql tables with the 4 reports needed having over 140 points of data each.  I am making the website in PHP and report generator in Java but I am having an issue finding the information on how to get the in memory PDF to load directly in the clients browser.  I figured on using a TCP client/server going from Java to PHP but how do I code it so that it doesn't have to be written to the server drive and be supplied as a link.  I also have no wish to rewrite 17,000 lines of Java to PHP as I am new to PHP.  Is there anyway to get this done?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can't you just make it so that the web request fires the java application and streams the pdf to php, which in turn sends it to the client?

Comment: Having the php query the java app and get the resulting stream won't be an problem.  My key issue is not knowing/understanding the code that would move the stream from the php port to the client.  Sadly, I'm very new to php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how long the java app would take to run, you could consider using `proc_open` to create a pipe to the java programme:

```
<?php
    $desc = array(array('pipe','r'),array('pipe','w'));
    $resource= proc_open('bash',$desc,$pipes);
    if (!is_resource($resource))
    {
        throw new Exception('PDF stream creation failed');
    }
    usleep(5);//for safety
    fwrite($pipes[0],'java mkPDF paras'."\n");//double quoted \n is crucial
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    usleep(100);//while java app is running;
    $pdf = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    proc_close($resource);
?>
```

This is just a basic example, that gets the streamed pdf in one big lump, so it's far from perfect. What you -IMO- should look into is getting the stream in chunks using a while loop. The [php man page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) contains a couple of examples of this, basically, repleace

```
usleep(100);//while java app is running;
$pdf = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
```

with:

```
usleep(10);//while java app is running;
$pdf = '';
while (($pdfBuff = fgets($pipes[1],1024)) !== null)
{
    $pdf.=$pdfBuff;//or echo, or whatever
}
fclose($pipes[1]);
```

The latter is untested, so I'm not sure if that will work in your case... but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

1. As said by [@Elias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230836/elias-van-ootegem) directly send web request to java application and stream the pdf to php.
2. Using web services,

   I. Develop some web services on java side that will send only data in any of the format like XML, jSon etc.

   II. Write a code to consume these web services and develop your code to generate the pdf and stream these pdf's.

There is one pdf generating lib. Please find the link [here](http://www.ifadey.com/2010/04/creating-pdf-using-php/)

Comment: So you are saying rather than create the pdf in Java with the code that is already written, I should generate it in the php because php does not have the ability to stream the data through itself. That is unfortunate.

Comment: I was in impression that there is no such feature in java side. And yes by doing this using web services will let you design your PDF your way.